# Rewriting MediaTek MT7921 Linux driver for FreeBSD

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, freebsd

New to BSD, coming from Linux. My laptop (Asus FX706LI) uses the MediaTek MT7921. Although I've never installed linux on this laptop, I know the driver is in Linux 5.12 and subsequent kernels. I am to the point that I'd like to try modifying the driver to work with FreeBSD. This is uncharted territory for me, but I have the PDFs for "FreeBSD Device Drivers" by Joseph Kong and "The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System" by Marshall McKusick. I will begin reading these books, but if you have any useful information or pointers as to where to start, I welcome them.

Comment: Pointer... don't look to create a full driver as your first project. Create a simple one even `Hello world!` then gradually expand it until you have enough knowledge & experience before tackling the wireless device.

Comment: I am sufficiently beyond a hello world application. I have done work with OpenGL, OpenAL, OpenGA, OpenNN, etc, and I have a rudimentary SysAdmin skillset.

Comment: Not with device drivers though...

Comment: True, the most technical I've gone with drivers is installation of officially unsupported drivers in Linux, where I basically had to find a service to add kernel modules then compile the driver and add it to the kernel. Rewriting the driver to work with another OS is beyond my current abilities. Currently my plan is to take NetBSD's kernel, FreeBSD's SysApps, then get the Graphics, Audio and WiFi drivers working, then write a Wayland shell that is compatible with GTK themes, maybe rewrite portions of WayFire to use Vulkan.

Comment: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=264300 suggests looking at LinuxKPI